# Error for Neural Network in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to program a neural network in R, and I am getting an error that states

> Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments.

It is occurring right after this step:

```
nn<-neuralnet(formula,data=train,hidden=10,threshold=0.01)
```

Could someone explain what this means? I'm fairly new to R so I didn't really understand the answers to similar questions. I'll attach the code below. Thanks in advance!

```
library(neuralnet)

dat <- read.csv("/Users/Sean/Documents/Cintas Stock Trailing.csv", header = TRUE)

## Features slected after the feature selection
vars <- c("X50.calendar.day.moving.average","asset_matched", "Beta", "CTAS.Enterprise.Value..In.Millions..Basically.the.first.value.is.11.5.B.",
          "EBITDA_matched" , "invested_matched" , "Close..Nasdaq.", "Open..Nasdaq.", "Price.of.Oil",
          "return_matched", "X50.Day.Simple.Moving.Average..S.P.500.", "tobin_matched","zmi_matched",
          "PE.Ratio", "Indicator")
Ycolumn <- "Indicator"

alldata <- dat[, vars];
y <- alldata$Indicator;

##remove NA and data cleaning
alldata_new <- na.omit(alldata);
data<- alldata_new
rm(alldata_new)

##splitting the data into training and testing
index <- sample(1:nrow(data),round(0.90*nrow(data)))
train <- data[index,]
test <- data[-index,]

formula <- paste(Ycolumn,paste(vars,collapse=' + '),sep=' ~ ')



nn<-neuralnet(formula,data=train,hidden=10,threshold=0.01)
plot(nn)

pr.nn <- compute(nn,test_[,1:13])

pr.nn_ <- pr.nn$net.result*(max(data$medv)-min(data$medv))+min(data$medv)
test.r <- (test_$medv)*(max(data$medv)-min(data$medv))+min(data$medv)

MSE.nn <- sum((test.r - pr.nn_)^2)/nrow(test_)
```

Here is a link to the data:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/iedu-attachments-message/ff398557faa9b034c9ab36cb200b049b_fd95a111761a10a8dec1203a47386578.csv

Comment: It sounds like a data problem, but we don't have your data

Comment: Let me attach the data as well then

Comment: NN cannot handle factor data, you have to remove them before running the model. Also you have to normalise the variable.

Comment: Okay I fixed the data and it's running smoothly now. Thanks for everything!